# Reduce list of lists by evaluating elements

Tags: r

How do I reduce a list of lists to only contain the values that live up to a certain criteria? I've seen similar questions, and looked at `Filter`, `Reduce`, etc. but can't seem to make anything work.

```
> h = list(A=c(1, 2, 3), B=c(2, 3, 4), C=c(0, 1, 2))
> h
$A
[1] 1 2 3

$B
[1] 2 3 4

$C
[1] 0 1 2
```

Desired output:

```
> MagicFunction(h, element >= 3)
$A
[1] 3

$B
[1] 3 4
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try,

```
Filter(length, lapply(h, function(i)i[i>=3]))

#$A
#[1] 3

#$B
#[1] 3 4
```

If you have elements with NA, then you can use `na.omit` to remove those, .i.e

```
h = list(A=c(1, 2, 3), B=c(2, 3, 4), C=c(0, 1, 2), D=NA)
Filter(length, lapply(h, function(i)na.omit(i[i>=3])))

#$A
#[1] 3

#$B
#[1] 3 4
```

An alternative would be,

```
h = list(A=c(1, 2, 3), B=c(2, 3, 4), C=c(0, 1, 2), D=c(NA, 7))
Filter(length, lapply(h, function(i)(i[i >= 3 & !is.na(i)])))

#$A
#[1] 3

#$B
#[1] 3 4

#$D
#[1] 7
```

Comment: Works perfectly! `lapply` removes the values, and `Filter` removes the empty lists. I'd like to add that `NA` can be searched or removed by using `is.na` within the square brackets.

Comment: If the `NA` is inside the list, eg. `D=c(NA, 7)`, `na.omit` gives some weird results.

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Yep, now all variants should be covered!

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with `purrr` and `map`. `map` applies the function across groups, then `discard(is_empty)` removes lists that contain no values (i.e. that were filtered out by the function). `~` is used to specify the function that is to be applied to each list and `.` is a placeholder for each list passing through the function.

```
library(purrr)

map(h, ~.[. >= 3]) %>% discard(is_empty)

$A
[1] 3

$B
[1] 3 4
```